# When the points of coproduct are the coproduct of points

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be a category with coproduct. The Yoneda functor $C^{op}\to Psh(C)$ preserves all limits but not colimits.

Suppose that $C$ has a terminal object, say $*$.

My question: can we say anything whether $\hom(*, A\sqcup B)=\hom(*, A)\sqcup \hom(*, B)$?

For a general diagram $J$ in $C$, suppose that $J$ is connected in certain sense. Under what condition, one can expect 
$$
\mathrm{cocone}(J, A\sqcup B)=\mathrm{cocone}(J, A)\sqcup \mathrm{cocone}(J, B).
$$
(It is easy to see that this holds for $Sets$.)

Comment: What on earth do you mean by homs from a diagram to a coproduct? Do you mean cocones?

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, cocones.

Comment: The claim is definitely not true in $\mathbf{Set}$ then: for instance, take $J$ to be a diagram constant at $2$...

Comment: @ZhenLin 2 is not connected.

Comment: Then you'll have to be more specific about what hypotheses $J$ satisfies, because I can certainly take the shape of $J$ to be connected.

Comment: @ZhenLin I admit that the question is vague. I am wondering whether the wrong intuition of the points of coproduct $A\sqcup B$ is the union of points of $A$ and $B$ can be fixed.

Comment: @ZhenLin Maybe one need a notion of connectedness on the objects of $C$ rather than the shape of diagram.

Answer (score 3):

For the purposes of this question it is best to assume that $\mathcal{C}$ has at least all finite coproducts, if not small coproducts. Let us say a **connected object** is an object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$ such that $\mathcal{C} (X, -) : \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$ preserves finite coproducts. For example, if $\mathcal{C} = \mathbf{Top}$, then this coincides with the notion of (non-empty) connected topological space. Note that the initial object of $\mathcal{C}$ is *never* connected.

Let $\mathcal{J}$ be a small category. It is known that the functor $\varprojlim : [\mathcal{J}, \mathbf{Set}] \to \mathbf{Set}$ preserves small coproducts if and only if $\mathcal{J}$ is connected. Thus, if $\mathcal{J}$ is a connected category, $X : \mathcal{J} \to \mathcal{C}$ is a diagram of connected objects, and ${\varinjlim}_\mathcal{J} X$ exists in $\mathcal{C}$, then ${\varinjlim}_\mathcal{J} X$ is also a connected object in $\mathcal{C}$. In other words, a connected colimit of connected objects is connected. Conversely, the coproduct of two connected objects is *never* connected: indeed, the canonical map 
$$\mathcal{C} (X + Y, X) \amalg \mathcal{C} (X + Y, Y) \to \mathcal{C} (X + Y, X + Y)$$
is injective but never surjective. (What would the preimage of $\mathrm{id}_{X + Y}$ be?)

Now suppose $\mathcal{C}$ has a terminal object $1$. There are very many examples of well-behaved categories where $1$ fails to be connected: for instance, if $\mathcal{C}$ is  $\mathbf{Sh} (X)$ or $\mathbf{Top}_{/ X}$ for some topological space $X$, then $1$ is connected if and only if $X$ is. But it sometimes happens that $1$ is connected, e.g. $\mathbf{Set}$, $\mathbf{sSet}$, $\mathbf{Cat}$...