# When do finite sets embed in a category?

Tags: category-theory

Let $FSet$ be the category of finite sets. Let $C$ be a category with binary coproduct and terminal object $*$.

My first question: when does $1\mapsto *$ extend to a functor $FSet\to C$ preserving coproducts? Is this functor an embedding such that $FSet$ is a full subcategory of $C$?

Second question: Denote the above functor by $\iota\colon FSet\to C$. When do we have an isomorphism of categories:

$$
C^{FSet}\cong C/FSet,
$$

where $C^{FSet}$ denotes the functor category $FSet\to C$, and $C/FSet$ is the comma/slice category for the functor $\iota$.

Basically, I am asking when a morphism $A\to 2$ gives a decomposition of $A$ (??).

Comment: Your second question is poorly phrased. It is not even true for $\mathbf{Set}$: one side is cocomplete, the other is not.

Comment: @ZhenLin I see, the left side is not what I intended to consider.

Answer (score 3):

If $\mathcal{C}$ has *finite* coproducts, then for any object $A$ in $\mathcal{C}$, there is a unique (up unique isomorphism) functor $\mathbf{FinSet} \to \mathcal{C}$ that preserves finite coproducts and sends $1$ to $A$. This is more or less obvious. It is neither full nor faithful in general. (Consider the case where $\mathcal{C}$ is $\mathbf{Set} \times \mathbf{Set}$ and the case where $\mathcal{C}$ is trivial.) However, if $A$ is a [connected object](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/716986/5191), then the embedding is faithful; and if *in addition* $A$ is the terminal object, then the embedding is fully faithful.

The second question, interpreted generously, has to do with the concept of [extensivity](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extensive+category). One definition is as follows: an extensive category is a category $\mathcal{C}$ with finite coproducts such that, for all objects $A$ and $B$, the functor
$$\mathcal{C}_{/ A} \times \mathcal{C}_{/ B} \to \mathcal{C}_{/ A \amalg B}$$
induced by binary coproduct is an equivalence of categories. Of course, $\mathbf{FinSet}$ is an extensive category. If $\mathcal{C}$ is an extensive category with a terminal object that is connected, then the induced embedding $\mathbf{FinSet} \to \mathcal{C}$ described in the first paragraph preserves finite limits (as well as finite coproducts).

Comment: A side question: since the isomorphism of categories preserves product, the coproduct commutes with pullbacks in an extensivity category?

Comment: In a certain sense. Read the link page.

Comment: What I expected is more. Let $A$ be finite set. We then have $C^A=C/(A\otimes 1)$. I wish this isomorphism is functorial in $A$, in suitable sense.

Comment: The functor is already natural.

Comment: Here by functorial I mean the following: Let $A\to B$ be a map of finite set, which can be viewed as a $B$-decomposition of $A$. A morphism $C_A\to A\otimes 1$ can be viewed as a $A$-decomposition of $C_A$. Now consider a square formed by $C_A\to A\otimes 1$ and $C_B\to B\otimes 1$. It corresponds to a morphism $C_A\to C_B$ that compatible with the decomposition of $A\to B$. I realize that this indeed follows from the extensivity immediately.

Comment: I figure out how to formulate the correct iso. Let $f:A\to B$ the a map of finite sets, denoted by $F$ the associated cograph. Then there is an isomorphism $C^F=C//(f\otimes 1)$, where $C//(f\otimes 1)$ is the category of commutative squares over $f\otimes 1$.