# An isomorphism of categories

Tags: category-theory

This is a corrected follow up to [When do finite sets embed in a category?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721328/when-do-finite-sets-embed-in-a-category)

Let $C$ be an (finite) [extensive category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extensive+category) with terminal object $1$. Let $I$ be an index category. Let $j: \mathrm{FinSet}\to C$ be the functor induced by $*\mapsto 1$. Let $f$ be a finite sets-valued presheaf on $I$, that is a functor $I^{op}\to \mathrm{FinSet}$. Let $F$ be the associated [category of elements](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+of+elements).

Then my question is whether there is an isomorphism of categories?
$$
[F, C]=[I^{op}, C]/j(f).
$$

Comment: Let $F:\mathbf{C}→\mathbf{D}$ be a functor. Then F is an isomorphism (of categories) iff there exists a functor $G:\mathbf{C}→\mathbf{D}$ such that:
$$GF:\mathbf{C}→\mathbf{C}\text{ is the identity functor }\operatorname{id}_\mathbf{C}\\
F_G:\mathbf{D}→\mathbf{D}\text{ is the identity functor }\operatorname{id}_\mathbf{D}$$Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @MaMing There is a canonical functor $[\mathcal{I}^\mathrm{op}, \mathcal{C}] \to [\mathcal{F}^\mathrm{op}, \mathcal{C}]$, induced by the projection $\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{I}$. It has a left adjoint that sends the terminal object in $[\mathcal{F}^\mathrm{op}, \mathcal{C}]$ to $j f$. So there is a canonical functor $[\mathcal{F}^\mathrm{op}, \mathcal{C}] \to [\mathcal{I}^\mathrm{op}, \mathcal{C}]_{/ j f}$, at least.

Comment: @ZhenLin The project is $\mathcal{F}\to I^{op}$, as wiki pages idicates https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_elements

Comment: You can choose either convention. I prefer to have the covariant one.

Comment: @ZhenLin Now I figure out the other direction, one fist consider $I=[1]$, which is easy to prove. So for $X\in [I^{op}, C]/jf$, we can decompose each $X_i$ for $i\in I$ and each arrow $X_i \to X_j$ for $j\to i$. To see that this defines a functor $F\to C$, I suppose that we can use the fact that the decomposition is unique.